# Order of magnitude of extremely abundant numbers and RH

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis, conjectures

I have always been intrigued by the fact that Riemann's hypothesis is [equivalent to the assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossally_abundant_number#Relation_to_the_Riemann_hypothesis) (you can find the scanned paper [here](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Robin_1984.pdf)) that the inequality $$\frac{\sigma(n)}n<e^\gamma  \log\log n \qquad\qquad\qquad(*)$$ holds for all $n > 5040$ (where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)). Since $(*)$ is somewhat "quantifiable", I am wondering:

> - Suppose there is an (obviously rather huge) $n$ that violates $(*)$. Then RH is false, so $\zeta(z)$ must have a minimal non trivial zero $z_0$ off the critical line. Taking $n_0$ to be the smallest such $n$, can anything be said about an upper (or, why not, lower) bound of $\Im(z_0)$ or of $\pm\Re(z_0-\frac12)$ in terms of $n_0$?
> - Conversely, if RH is false, so there is such an (obviously rather huge) smallest $z_0$, are there bounds in terms of $|z_0|$ for the smallest $n_0> 5040$ violating $(*)$?

It is well-known that if $n_0$ exists, it must be an [extremely abundant number (see Thm. 6)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Nazar/nazar4.pdf), whence the title.

I am aware that *a priori*, there is no relationship between both orders of magnitude. A priori... that's why I am asking.

Comment: Have you worked through Robin's paper proving the equivalence? If not, that's a good place to start....

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I have gone through the scanned version http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Robin_1984.pdf. The most relevant part for the current question would be section 4 ("Comportement de $\sigma(n)$ si l'hypothèse de Riemann n'est pas vraie"), which has some interesting ideas but nothing helpful here.

Comment: Is it obvious that your putative least violator $n_0$ must be colossally abundant (CA)? E.g. ([2014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1342.11009)) only claims XA, where CA $\not\supset$ XA $\subset$ SA.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thank you! You are right, I had kept in mind from the Wikipedia page the assertion "It is known that Robin's inequality, if it ever fails to hold, will fail for a colossally abundant number n; thus the Riemann hypothesis is in fact equivalent to Robin's inequality holding for every colossally abundant number n > 5040.". At first I had just thought about counterexamples in general, but bounds of course only make sense for extremal ones. I have now corrected the title and included a link.

Comment: Those extremely abundant numbers must be exceedingly rare.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Sure enough. Compare XA (https://oeis.org/A217867) with CA (https://oeis.org/A004490) and SA (https://oeis.org/A004394). If you [paste "extremely abundant numbers" into the oeis search box](https://oeis.org/search?q=%22extremely+abundant+numbers%22&sort=&language=english&go=Search), you have all three on the same page.